# Best approach to execute service in Android

Tags: java, android, android-service, background-service, android-intentservice

I have a service that have an variable life time. It may execute from 5 minutes to 2 hours (for example). So I'm looking for the best approach to do that, and my service must achieve the following features:

- Send (to my server) lat-long every 5 seconds and some extra information (`string`'s, `boolean`'s and `int`'s)

I have tried a "normal" service and tried to do something like this to achieve this:

```
public class MyFiveSecondsService extends Service {
    private Handler handler;
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //here send my new data
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(handler == null){
            handler = new Handler();
        }

        handler.post(r);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Actually that code works, but I got some performance problems with that approach, so I tried to do something like this:

```
public class SendUniquePositionIntentService extends IntentService {

    public SendUniquePositionIntentService() {
        super("co.bomboapp.Service.IntentService.SendUniquePositionIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //do the logic here
    }
}

public class MyFiveSecondsService extends Service {
    private Handler handler;
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //call my SendUniquePositionIntentService here
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(handler == null){
            handler = new Handler();
        }

        handler.post(r);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

And that approach haven't worked, when I had closed the app any service kept running. So before start any other attempt to achieve this, I want some direction, what's the best approach to do this "infinite loop service" and keep the performance?

I'm using `Android` 4.1 as min `API`, and targeting 5.0 `API`.
My test device is a `Nexus` 5 running `Android` 6.
Right now I'm using `parse.com` as database.

Comment: Services are designed to be still running after your activity gets destroyed. So don't forget to stop your service when it's work is done

Comment: It stops it self at the right moment, but thanks, anyway!

Comment: why you don't call SendUniquePositionIntentService directly? I think it is enough to realize your demands use SendUniquePositionIntentService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"I have tried a "normal" service...but I got some performance problems"*

By default, a service runs on the application's main thread, so when you create a handler with

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(handler == null){
        handler = new Handler();
    }
    ...
}
```

the handler is associated with the main thread's `Looper` and all messages and runnables are delivered and later executed on the thread. That's the reason of the *"performance problems"*. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics):

> Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your application's main thread by default...

Regarding the second approach and the part

*"...when I had closed the app any service kept running"*

you haven't mentioned how exactly you "close" the app, but what I can see is

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

which means that if the system kills the service it, by default, will be recreated. So if "closing" your app means killing it, the following chain of actions takes place:

1. The system recreates `MyFiveSecondsService`,
2. `onStartCommand()` is called and the handler posts the runnable
3. within the `run()` method `SendUniquePositionIntentService` is started

From the documentation of [`onStartCommand()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29):

> the default implementation calls onStart(Intent, int) and returns either START_STICKY or START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

Note that starting a service from another one (like starting `SendUniquePositionIntentService` from `MyFiveSecondsService` in your case) is redundant unless you intended to.

The final part of your question is confusing to me. On one hand it doesn't work for you because *"...any service kept running"* but, on the other hand, you'd like *"do this "infinite loop service""*...?

If you only need to send such information as *"strings, booleans and ints"* to a server (without any feedback to the component that started the service), I suppose it's simply enough for you to use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService). This is a "out-of-box" framework that does its work on a background thread (letting you avoid freezing the main thread) and stops itself once it's done. As an example you can use the documentation on [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) - it's well written.

Also note that the behaviour of a service after killing it by the system depends on the flag returned by `onStartCommand()`. E.g. use [`START_NOT_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) to not recreate the service after killing the app or [`START_REDELIVER_INTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) to recreate it with the last `Intent` redelivered.

Comment: my intention using both a service and serveral intentServices was to the service keep the "infinite loop", even if the user close the app, while the intentService has a dedicated thread to do the hard work.

Comment: @guisantogui Why _"using serveral intentServices"_? Wouldn't it be enough to start just one `IntentService` and run multiple threads within it. (Take a look at [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to manage the threads). Within `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()` you could do your work as "infinite" as you'd like. What is important is to be sure the service is alive after closing the app which can be managed by appropriate flag as per the answer.